# How to filtred when I have different models

Tags: odoo

This is the .py:

```py
class Travsup(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.travsup'
    attachment_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.attachement')
    ouvrage_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.ouvrage',domain="?????")

class Attachement(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.attachement'
    travSup_ids =   fields.One2many('facturation.travsup','attachment_id')
    contrat_id  =   fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat',string='Contrat',required=True)


class Contrat(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.contrat'
    ouvrage_ids = fields.One2many('facturation.ouvrage', 'contrat_id', string='Ouvrages')

class Ouvrage(models.Model):
    _name = 'facturation.ouvrage'
    contrat_id = fields.Many2one('facturation.contrat', string='Contrat')
```

How to filtred ouvrage, when i change contrat_id of attachement model i get all
 ouvrage of model ouvrage of the same contrat_id of ouvrage model.

if Attachement.contrat_id == Ouvrage.contrat_id then travSup_ids.ouvrage_id = Ouvrage.id

Comment: to have all ouvrage in ouvrage_id field   when I change contat_id of my attachment model

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can specify the domain like this in your form view:

```xml
<!-- this field must appear in the form so we can use it in domain -->
<field name="contrat_id"/>

<field name="travSup_ids">
    <tree....>
        <field name="ouvrage_id" domain="[('contrat_id', '=', parent.contrat_id)]/>

    </tree>
    <form>
        ....
        ....
        <field name="ouvrage_id" domain="[('contrat_id', '=', parent.contrat_id)]/>
    </form>
</field>
```

In embaded form or tree you can access the field of the current form by
using `parent.field_name`